# lesscss @import with absolute path

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am having issue trying to refer from a less file another less file using absolute syntax:

Less file A with location

```
$find `pwd` -name auth0.less
/Users/panos/dcimsupport/struxureon/auth0/src/main/resources/css/auth0.less
```

imports Less file B

```
@import '/bootstrap/less/so_colors.less';
```

Now, the so_colors.less has location

```
find `pwd` -name so_colors.less
/Users/panos/dcimsupport/struxureon/auth0/src/main/resources/bootstrap/less/so_colors.less
```

The above fails with

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /Users/panos/dcimsupport/struxureon/auth0/src/main/resources/css/bootstrap/less/so_colors.less
```

It seems that lesscss is like jailed to the css folder. I know that if I import as ../bootstrap/.....less it will work but then I have to go as up in directories as required which i'd rather not. Is there some other solution to that? There is limitation though, that bootstrap folder cannot be under css  folder

I have used both

```
<groupId>biz.gabrys.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>lesscss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

and

```
<groupId>org.lesscss</groupId>
<artifactId>lesscss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

with configuration such as

```
<configuration>
<sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</sourceDirectory>
<outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/classes/resources</outputDirectory>
<compress>true</compress>
<includes>
    <include>css/**/*.less</include>
    <include>layouts/**/*.less</include>
    <include>page/**/*.less</include>
    <include>pages/**/*.less</include>
</includes>
```

Comment: I assume that `<groupId>org.lesscs</groupId>` is ok?

Comment: have you tried changing to `<groupId>org.lesscss</groupId>`?

Comment: That typo was taken from unused profile, i changed it but no change in the outcome.

Comment: the import would be relative to the importing file, which is located in the `/css` folder. So why not import like `@import '../bootstrap/etc/etc', as you mentioned? I guess I dont understand exactly what you'd like to do.

Comment: Because there are can be atm such src/main/resources/macroA/css/aLESSFile.less which would mean to link to the bootstrap i would have to ../../../../bootstrap/etc if i count correctly the ../

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How plugins works**

The `biz.gabrys.maven.plugins` plugin treats the path `/bootstrap/less/so_colors.less` as an absolute. It does not set the `sourceDirectory` as a root, so it is looking for `/bootstrap/less/so_colors.less` instead of `/Users/panos/dcimsupport/struxureon/auth0/src/main/resources/bootstrap/less/so_colors.less`. That file does not exist so the plugin uses fallback and treats it as a relative to `/Users/panos/dcimsupport/struxureon/auth0/src/main/resources/css/auth0.less`. That is the reason why it is looking for `/Users/panos/dcimsupport/struxureon/auth0/src/main/resources/css/bootstrap/less/so_colors.less`.

The `org.lesscss` plugin works similar.

---

**Your idea for improvement**

I can try to add such improvement to my plugin, but first I need finish some migration process. Unfortunately this means that I can release that improvement not in the near future (e.g. at the end of 2016).

The `org.lesscss` plugin is not supported by the author and no one else.

---

**Solution**

For now you can only use relative paths with `../`.